# Indoor A/C fan doesn't stop automatically

Tags: air-conditioning

The fan on my indoor A/C unit doesn't stop when the dialed in temperature is reached. It keeps a constant temperature just fine and the outdoor unit motor shuts down when the temperature is reached. I just find it strange (and wasteful) that the indoor blower never stops running, even on auto.

Is this normal? I read somewhere that this might be intended since the thermostat is embedded in the indoor unit and needs a constant airflow to read the room temperature. Only found this info in a single place so I'm not sure how credible this is.

My unit is a Daikin FTX-KV.

Comment: Does the On/Auto switch turn the fan on and off properly, when the AC is set to Off?

Comment: @Mazura Not sure I completly understood your question, but turning the AC off does switch the fan off as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, that's normal for mini-splits. It also keeps the room air circulating, which is especially important if it's used as heating - hot air will accumulate near the ceiling, so it blows it back down to the floor.

That unit has a variable speed fan motor, so when the unit is idle it's likely at minimum speed - probably single-digit watts.